# SwiftUI Using onReceive with Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I try to call a function when view appear, but because this view is may not appear before set core data so I can't use "onAppear" or even put the code inside "init" because both don't work, Instead I want to use "onReceive" with core data entity's property "@NSManaged", But I don't know who to implement this

Example Code

```
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if sublist.index == 0 {
                mainSection
            } else {
                section
            }
        }
        .onReceive(entity.propertiy, perform: 
          // code here 
         )
        .onAppear(perform: onAppearAction) // Don't work
        .onChange(of: list.wrappedSortType) { _ in onChangeListSortTypeAction() }
        .onChange(of: list.isSortUp) { _ in onChangeListSortDirectionAction()}
        }
```

Comment: It’s not clear _what_ it is that isn’t working. In what context is this happening ?

Comment: The "onAppear" will non called because we need to set some core data first then the view appear

Comment: I'm not sure, but look at this article and see if you can use the .task modifier on your View. https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/06/28/the-power-of-task-view-modifier-in-swiftui/

Comment: “need to set some core data first”, what does this mean?

Comment: I bet they want to set the initial sort order which is challenging

Comment: The issue is the initial core data didn't crated and I don't know why is that so I try to use on receive to trigger the first initial of core date